# Calling unix shell script remotely from C#

Tags: c#, shell, unix

In my current project, i need to call a Unix shell script from the C# application. I also need to get the response back whether the script has been execute successfully or any error has occurred.

The C# program is running on a Windows machine. I need to connect to a Unix machine and execute the script.

Can anyone let me know how this can be done using C#?

Comment: Are you running the C# program on the Unix box?

Comment: C# program is in windows machine. I need to connect to unix machine and execute the script.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this solve your problem?

[sharpSsh - A Secure Shell (SSH) library for .NET](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/sharpssh.aspx?msg=2169540)

**Update**

Refer to the developer's site for [SharpSSH](http://web.archive.org/web/20120825185436/http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx) for more information on how to use the tool.

**Update 2**

- change link of developer site to archived link.

Comment: I have checked this. This seems to be promising. But as the author mentioned its not complete. We are getting error when connecting to remote machine. We are trying to solve this out.

Comment: Hi, We tried out, but unable to solve the issue. We are getting timed out error when connecting to remote machine.

Comment: Hi, We tried out, but unable to solve the issue. We are getting timed out error when connecting to remote machine.

Comment: Hi, have you accessed the sharpSsh's author [site](http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx)

Comment: Using the source directly from author's site worked for us. many thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

A straight forward way of preforming this using [System.Diagnostics.Process](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.aspx)

```
// Start the child process.
 Process p = new Process();
 // Redirect the error stream of the child process.
 p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
 p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";
 p.Start();
 // Do not wait for the child process to exit before
 // reading to the end of its redirected error stream.
 // p.WaitForExit();
 // Read the error stream first and then wait.
 string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
 p.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Thanks Terrance. The C# application runs in a windows environment and i need to connect to remote unix box to execute the shell script there. Is there any direct method for this?

Answer (score 1):

Even i had the same problem, i have googled for solution for around 1 month.

Finally, i have decided to use plink.exe (command line version of putty.exe) to connect to unix box and execute a script there.

You have to use plink through c# process, i have tried it and this works amazingly.

But rite now the problem i am facing is when i am running a script from c# process i am unable to pass arguments to that script. Probably it would be rite to say that i do not know how to do that.

Regards 
-Aakash

Comment: Hi Aakash, as OnesimusUnbound told check out sharpSSH from the orginal site, http://www.tamirgal.com/blog/page/SharpSSH.aspx

Comment: Yes Hari, but i i liked the plink rather than SharpSSH, plink is more stable.